# Overflow-y not working when overflow-x is hidden?

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV that contains several other divs. I need divs to be able to peek out of the parent vertically, but not horizontally.

I thought using `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` would solve this little problem, but I can only get either x and y to show, or get them both to hide.

My CSS and HTML:

```css
.game {
  position:absolute;
  width:400px; height:300px;
  top:100px; left:100px;
  background-color:#cccccc;

  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:visible;
}

.block1 {
  position:absolute;
  width:100px; height:100px;
  top:-50px; left:150px;
  background-color:#ffcccc;
}

.block2 {
  position:absolute;
  width:100px; height:100px;
  top:150px; left:-50px;
  background-color:#ccffcc;
}
```

```html
<div class="game">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

[See this JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/p9bvn/) both child divs are cut off, even though overflow-y is set to visible.

Comment: [this may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue)

Comment: Thanks. Sadly it seems that you can't combine overflow-x and overflow-y if one of them is hidden. (it's beyond me why you can even specify x and y, if they can't be different from one another...)
I'm also not sure about how to solve this issue in my particular case.

Comment: I agree that it makes no sense to me either that you cannot set one to `hidden` and the other to `visible` and have it work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Structural Change Needed

This gets what you want if it works otherwise (I don't know if the html/css changes affect other aspects of your game). It solves it by layering the "game" so that its vertical direction fills the entire screen, and then your "window" (grey area) is set by a child div. This allows the `overflow: hidden` horizontally, but not have it vertically.

### [See fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/p9bvn/7/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="game">
    <div>
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <div class="block2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0;}
.game {
    position:absolute;
    width:400px; 
    height:100%;
    top: 0; 
    left:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.game > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#cccccc;
}

.block1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px; height:100px;
    top:-50px; left:150px;
    background-color:#ffcccc;
}

.block2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px; height:100px;
    top:150px; left:-50px;
    background-color:#ccffcc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Still, I will keep wondering why they added overflow-x and overflow-y.

Comment: I'll wonder with you. Here is a helpful (though slightly outdated, but I think generally still valid) [link illustrating the various combinations](http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html).

Comment: spent ages trying to figure out a solution then searching around, this answer works perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

try Changing your game class to

```
.game {
     width:400px; height:300px;
    top:100px; left:100px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Thanks,
Dhiraj